# FILTRAR EN EXCEL CON UN SOLO CAMPO DE TEXTO EN VARIAS COLUMNAS

Tags: excel

He creado una hoja excel y me gustaría saber como puedo filtrar varias columnas a la vez con un solo campo de texto de introducción de datos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)